# Mongodb using wrong index

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-indexes, compound-index

I have multiple indices on a collection as following. Particularly I want a query to use `"gTs_1_RE_H_1_l_1"`, but the query is using `"gTs_1"` instead!

```
{
    "0" : {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "_id" : 1
        },
        "ns" : "week_raw_tweet_db.tweets",
        "name" : "_id_"
    },
    "1" : {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "gTs" : 1
        },
        "ns" : "week_raw_tweet_db.tweets",
        "name" : "gTs_1",
        "expireAfterSeconds" : 604800
    },
    "2" : {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "uN" : 1
        },
        "ns" : "week_raw_tweet_db.tweets",
        "name" : "uN_1"
    },
    "3" : {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "gTs" : 1,
            "RE_H" : 1,
            "l" : 1
        },
        "ns" : "week_raw_tweet_db.tweets",
        "name" : "gTs_1_RE_H_1_l_1",
        "background" : 1
    }
}
```

Here I have a index on '`gTs`' alone (A TTL Based index) and a compound index with '`gTs`' and '`RE_H`' as first two keys. (`"gTs_1_RE_H_1_l_1"`)

Now, I'm trying to execute this query:

```
db.tweets.find( {

                    "RE_H" : NumberLong("484001755192636620"),                  
                    "gTs" : {
                        "$lte" : ISODate("2014-03-18T22:00:00Z"),
                        "$gte" : ISODate("2014-03-17T21:00:00Z")
                    }
                }).explain()
```

This should as per my knowledge, use `"gTs_1_RE_H_1_l_1"`, but surprisingly it is using, 
`"gTs_1"` as mentioned by this output:

```
{
    "cursor" : "BtreeCursor gTs_1",
    "isMultiKey" : false,
    "n" : 46508,
    "nscannedObjects" : 365746,
    "nscanned" : 365746,
    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 370493,
    "nscannedAllPlans" : 370494,
    "scanAndOrder" : false,
    "indexOnly" : false,
    "nYields" : 1,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "millis" : 1509,
    "indexBounds" : {
        "gTs" : [ 
            [ 
                ISODate("2014-03-17T21:00:00.000Z"), 
                ISODate("2014-03-18T22:00:00.000Z")
            ]
        ]
    },
    "server" : "Frrole-API1:27017"
}
```

How ever, if I provide an hint, it does pick up right index. So, if I run following query:

```
db.tweets.find( {

                    "RE_H" : NumberLong("484001755192636620"),                  
                    "gTs" : {
                        "$lte" : ISODate("2014-03-18T22:00:00Z"),
                        "$gte" : ISODate("2014-03-17T21:00:00Z")
                    }
                }).hint("gTs_1_RE_H_1_l_1").explain()
```

I get following output:

```
/* 0 */
{
    "cursor" : "BtreeCursor gTs_1_RE_H_1_l_1",
    "isMultiKey" : true,
    "n" : 46508,
    "nscannedObjects" : 233224,
    "nscanned" : 233541,
    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 233224,
    "nscannedAllPlans" : 233541,
    "scanAndOrder" : false,
    "indexOnly" : false,
    "nYields" : 3,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "millis" : 1874,
    "indexBounds" : {
        "gTs" : [ 
            [ 
                true, 
                ISODate("2014-03-18T22:00:00.000Z")
            ]
        ],
        "RE_H" : [ 
            [ 
                NumberLong(484001755192636620), 
                NumberLong(484001755192636620)
            ]
        ],
        "l" : [ 
            [ 
                {
                    "$minElement" : 1
                }, 
                {
                    "$maxElement" : 1
                }
            ]
        ]
    },
    "server" : "Frrole-API1:27017"
}
```

**Can someone please help me understand what's going On!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see from the output, the query that uses the simpler index is *faster* by about 300ms, that's why mongodb uses that index. MongoDB's optimization doesn't try to understand the query path and guess how fast it will be, it simply executes different queries and **measures which one is fastest**. Your MongoDB has learned that it's faster using the simple `gTs` index. It will automatically test this from time to time by running different queries in parallel.

> This should as per my knowledge, use "gTs_1_RE_H_1_l_1", but surprisingly it is using, "gTs_1" as mentioned by this output:

That is not really surprising. You should review the documentation on indexing, in particular [the section about sorting](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/sort-results-with-indexes/#sort-subset-does-not-start-at-the-index-beginning). While you don't request a sort here, you're using range query (`$lte` and its siblings), which is very similar. You will at least need to change the order of the indexes to `RE_H`, `gTs` such that the index for the equals constraint comes first, then the range query.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the order of defining the indexes is also effective in selecting it, for example :

```
{
    "0" : {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "_id" : 1
        },
        "ns" : "week_raw_tweet_db.tweets",
        "name" : "_id_"
    },
     "1" : {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "gTs" : 1,
            "RE_H" : 1,
            "l" : 1
        },
        "ns" : "week_raw_tweet_db.tweets",
        "name" : "gTs_1_RE_H_1_l_1",
        "background" : 1
    },
    "2" : {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "gTs" : 1
        },
        "ns" : "week_raw_tweet_db.tweets",
        "name" : "gTs_1",
        "expireAfterSeconds" : 604800
    },
    "3" : {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "uN" : 1
        },
        "ns" : "week_raw_tweet_db.tweets",
        "name" : "uN_1"
    }
}
```